# SSD full after swapping from Ubuntu (some kind of leak?)

Tags: 16.04, ssd, disk, crouton

I'm working on an Acer Chromebook 15 with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. My SSD has ~10.5 GB total, with only 5 GB used. The last few times I've logged out of Ubuntu or had it fall asleep, it restarts into ChromeOS with the warning the device disk is full. There are 0 B remaining. Something has suddenly eaten 5+ GB of my disk.

Has anyone else heard of this? My google-fu hasn't yielded any solutions. The last couple times, I've been able to delete some download files, and it will eventually clear itself out. For some reason, swapping back to Ubuntu helps it realize the amount is disk space is actually used. This time, there's nothing to delete, and I'm having trouble figuring out what I can delete to have the room to switch over to Ubuntu.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

I poked around a bit, and it looks like the culprit is probably in /mnt/stateful_partition. I'm not sure where I should delve from here. Hopefully it helps narrow it down.

Output from `df -h`:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                1.7G  1.6G   86M  96% /
devtmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmp                      1.9G  192K  1.9G   1% /tmp
run                      1.9G  548K  1.9G   1% /run
shmfs                    1.9G   19M  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                 11G   11G     0 100% /mnt/stateful_partition
/dev/sda8                 12M   24K   12M   1% /usr/share/oem
/dev/mapper/encstateful  3.2G   59M  3.1G   2% /mnt/stateful_partition/encrypted
media                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /media
none                     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
imageloader              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/imageloader
```

Output from `mount`:

```
/dev/dm-0 on / type ext2 (ro,relatime,seclabel)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,size=1986368k,nr_inodes=496592,mode=755)
none on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
none on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime)
tmp on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=605,mode=750)
shmfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/stateful_partition type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,seclabel,commit=600,data=ordered)
/dev/sda8 on /usr/share/oem type ext4 (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /home type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,seclabel,commit=600,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/encstateful on /mnt/stateful_partition/encrypted type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,seclabel,discard,commit=600,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/encstateful on /var type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,seclabel,discard,commit=600,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/encstateful on /home/chronos type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,seclabel,discard,commit=600,data=ordered)
run on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755)
run on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755)
media on /media type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
/dev/sda1 on /usr/local type ext4 (rw,nodev,noatime,seclabel,commit=600,data=ordered)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu)
/opt/google/containers/android/system.raw.img on /opt/google/containers/android/rootfs/root type squashfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
/usr/share/mount-passthrough/rootfs.squashfs on /opt/google/containers/arc-removable-media/mountpoints/container-root type squashfs (ro,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
/opt/google/containers/arc-sdcard/rootfs.squashfs on /opt/google/containers/arc-sdcard/mountpoints/container-root type squashfs (ro,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
/opt/google/containers/arc-obb-mounter/rootfs.squashfs on /opt/google/containers/arc-obb-mounter/mountpoints/container-root type squashfs (ro,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,noprefix)
imageloader on /run/imageloader type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755)
debugfs on /run/debugfs_gpu type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=605,mode=750)
/dev/sda1 on /home/chronos/user type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,commit=600,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /home/user/02d44d5ef61df73bb9b079a0851db0426ccb854c type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,commit=600,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /home/chronos/u-02d44d5ef61df73bb9b079a0851db0426ccb854c type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,commit=600,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /home/root/02d44d5ef61df73bb9b079a0851db0426ccb854c type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,commit=600,data=ordered)
```

Edit2:

I think I've found the culprit but still have no idea how to proceed. Here's the output from `lsblk`.

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0  14.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  10.8G  0 part /mnt/stateful_partition
├─sda2    8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3    8:3    0     2G  0 part 
├─sda4    8:4    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0     2G  0 part 
├─sda6    8:6    0   512B  0 part 
├─sda7    8:7    0   512B  0 part 
├─sda8    8:8    0    16M  0 part /usr/share/oem
├─sda9    8:9    0   512B  0 part 
├─sda10   8:10   0   512B  0 part 
├─sda11   8:11   0     8M  0 part 
└─sda12   8:12   0    16M  0 part 
loop0     7:0    0   3.2G  0 loop 
└─encstateful
  254:1    0   3.2G  0 dm   /mnt/stateful_partition/encrypted
loop1     7:1    0 449.2M  1 loop /opt/google/containers/android/rootfs/root
loop2     7:2    0     4K  1 loop /opt/google/containers/arc-removable-media/mou
loop3     7:3    0     4K  1 loop /opt/google/containers/arc-sdcard/mountpoints/
loop4     7:4    0     4K  1 loop /opt/google/containers/arc-obb-mounter/mountpo
zram0   253:0    0   5.6G  0 disk [SWAP]
```

The space held by zram0 is pretty much exactly the space that's missing. Some research tells it has something to do with external drives (I think?). With that in mind, I am using an SD card to run programs like IPython and Matlab. It might be a problem with it being improperly unmounted, but restarting my computer doesn't clear it out. If someone can help me reset zram0, I think that'll solve the issue.

The issue has been solved! It wasn't even an issue with swap files or anything like that. Running `sudo du --max-depth=9 --human-readable / | sort --human-numeric-sort` led me to the culprit: my vpn's manager log file. Clearing that out cleared out literally 7.5 GB.

Thanks to everyone that helped out!! I appreciate it greatly!!

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you edit your post and add the output of `df -h` and `mount` ?

Comment: `zram0` resides in memory, not on the disk. Is `sda1` the partition where Ubuntu is installed? If yes, it appears a bit small. Have you ever removed old , unused kernels?

Comment: sda1 is where Ubuntu is installed. I've run the autoremove and clean functions recently, so that should be ok. I believe I successfully reset my swap file, so I have some space now, but sda1 is still completely full.

Looking at "sudo du --max-depth=3", there are 11GB in /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton. That seems like way too much, right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the setup is using the /dev/zram0 device as a swap partition.
Here is a pretty good explanation on how that works:

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Zram

I'm not sure if this is actually the 'disk' flash memory or RAM that is being used.
You can try to disable the swap by doing :

`swapoff /dev/zram0` and see if that fixes the issue (make sure to do it before it's full).

Then you can lookup on how to create and enable a different swap partition if needed and probably modify `/etc/fstab`

to not set it at boot. Good luck!